# A formal way of saying 'rub it in'.

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I am trying to find a formal phrase equivalent to the colloquial expression'rub it it.'

> **rub it in**  (informal)
>   if someone rubs it in, they keep talking about something that makes you feel embarrassed or upset I know I made a mistake, but you don't have to rub it in.

Source: 
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rub+it+in

Comment: "Continue to massage the emollient."

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that "don't rub it in" is an allusion to rubbing salt into a person's wounds, to make them hurt more. Christine Ammer, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Clichés*, second edition (2006) confirms that the connection is likely:

> **rub it in, to** To stress something unpleasant or annoying in a teasing way; to ADD INSULT TO INJURY. The *it* in this expression may well be the salt that is in the much older related term, to *rub salt into a wound*, which dates from late medieval times (or earlier) and is still current. Rubbing it in originated in America; T.A. Burke used it in 1851 (*Polly Peaseblossom's Wedding*): "When it comes to rubbin' it in, I always ... roars up." Also related is the cliché to *rub one's nose in it*, meaning to reminfd one of a humiliating error or experience. [Citation omitted.] It alludes to rubbing a dog's nose into a mess it has made.

A formal way to refer to conduct that has an effect similar to that of having salt rubbed into one's wounds is to say that the conduct "exacerbates the original injury [or embarrassment]."

According to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2203), *exacerbate* means

> to make more violent, bitter, or severe {the proposed shutdown ... would *exacerbate* unemployment problems —*Science*}

Answer (score 2):

One option is **"wouldn't let him/her forget"**:

> Remember that really uncomfortable time Terrence Howard took the podium at the 2015 Oscars and could barely get his words out? He does. Painfully. And Jimmy Fallon **wouldn’t let him forget it** anyway. - [*Terrence Howard Explains His Super-Awkward Oscars Moment to Jimmy Fallon*, Yahoo movies, 3 March 2015](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/terrence-howard-jimmy-fallon-video-oscars-112615298137.html)

An alternative would be to **humiliate someone over something**.

> Katherine's mother was already dead and Lord Edmund Howard proceeded to  marry twice more, on both occasions to widows, Dorothy Troyes and Margaret Jennings (she who so **cruelly humiliated him over his accident**) without having any more children - or for that matter solving his economic situation. -  Antonia Fraser, *The Six Wives of Henry VIII*, 1993.